# Perform a check and redirect to a page at the start of a dot net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dot net mvc application and want to perform a database check about whether the user has accepted the terms and conditions or not at the start of the application and redirect the user to the terms and condition page based on the result. Where should I place the code snippet ?

Till now I tried to redirect from global.asax file to a route and then calling a method from the control to perform the check  But however it is  giving the Response does not exist in the currrent context.

I tried this piece of code :

```
 Response.RedirectToRoute("Terms",false);
```

I am very new to this so please excuse if the question really dumb.

Comment: Use some javascript in the view to redirect the page

Comment: @mituw16  I have edited the question and I am using MVC 5

Answer (score 0):

Place your code snippet in the ActionResult of the Index Page(which is the default page that loads when the application starts.) in the HomeController.

Get your user from either a session and check against the user in your database to see if they have read the terms and conditions.

It will look something like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var user = Session["loggedUser"] as User;
    user = db.Users.Find(user.id);
    if(!user.hasReadTerms)
    {
        return Redirect("/Terms");
    }else
    {
        //continue
    }
}
```